# My first name has a period in it, but I can't book an airline ticket with a period in my first name, can I still fly?

Tags: passports, spanish-language

My first name, as written in my passport, has a period in it: "Ma." However, the field on the airline's website does not allow special characters in the name.

Since it's supposed to be spelled "Ma.", will I be allowed to fly if I just put "Ma"?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132957/discussion-on-question-by-maria-my-first-name-has-a-period-in-it-but-i-cant-bo).

Answer (score 29):

Yes, you will be allowed to fly without a period in your name on the ticket.

Note that your passport's machine-readable zone (the two rows of standardized characters at the bottom of the main identification page) does not include a period.  (The only characters allowed there are `A` through `Z`, `0` through `9`, and `<`.)

Comment: Cool. I think I'll change my name to "<3"

Comment: I believe `<` has a special role, though even though it appears in the MRZ, I don't think it can be part of any of the fields.

Comment: Not hyphens?  Hyphenated names are pretty common in some parts of the world, surprised they'd not be included.

Comment: @jcaron the standard doesn't have much to say about non-alphanumeric characters in text fields of the visual inspection zone.  It seems to say that they're not allowed, but then it makes certain provisions for dealing with certain non-alphanumeric characters when translating to the MRZ, allowing them by implication.  The main problem would be that of representing the VIZ date in the MRZ. Since punctuation characters other than hyphen, comma, and apostrophe "shall be omitted from the MRZ, (i.e. no filler character shall be inserted in their place in the MRZ)" and "numeric characters should...

Comment: @jcaron "...not be written in the name fields of the VIZ; however, where the use of numeric characters is a legal naming convention in the issuing State, these should be represented in Roman numerals," it would seem that `<3` would have to be represented in the VIZ as `<III` and in the MRZ as `III`.  I wonder whether [Jennifer 8. Lee](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jennifer_8._Lee)'s passport has `LEE<<JENNIFER<VIII` in its MRZ.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker If you're going there, do it properly.  Little Bobby Tables...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman hyphens, commas, and apostrophes are the three punctuation marks that have specific instructions.  Hyphens are to be represented with the filler character `<`, so the MRZ representation of a hyphenated name is the same as it would be if the names were entirely separate.  That is, "Ann-Margret Olsson" and "Ann Margret Olsson" are both represented as `OLSSON<<ANN<MARGRET`.

Comment: @phoog: I don't think hyphenated surnames yield the same data as space-separated names.  By my understanding, John Smith Jones would be `JONES<<JOHN<SMITH`, but `JOHN SMITH-JONES` would be `SMITH<JONES<<JOHN`, would it not?

Comment: @supercat if the first person is Mr. Smith Jones, with a double non-hyphenated surname and the given name John (analogous to the real-world example of Ralph Vaughan Williams), then the MRZ would also be `SMITH<JONES<<JOHN` as it is for your second example.  If the first person is Mr. Jones, with a single surname and given names John Smith, then the MRZ would be as you suggest.  The presence or absence of the hyphen is immaterial; what matters is which parts of the name are the "primary identifier" (surname or surnames) and which parts are the "secondary identifier" (given name or given names).